# Wordpress, Siteorigin pagebuilder. How to create relationship between page and post?

Tags: php, wordpress, siteorigin

So I am using `Siteorigin Pagebuilder` to create my custom pages. I am creating a page that is built using different posts. So Page structure is something like this:

PLEASE Don't mind the markup :) its just to visually display the structure

```
 <page>
    <post id="25"></post>
    <post id="26"></post>
    and etc...
 </page>
```

So i am looking for a way where I can grab that particular `ID` and store it in a `li` item.
At the moment I can get all post `ID's'` but not related to that page. I don't want a hardcoded solution. This sidebar must be flexible as all pages will have the same sidebar but `li` items will be related only to their page.

is there any `WP` way around it?